# chown/chmod/chgrp on Users/____/Library without disabling SIP?

Tags: permission, sip, acl

I know how to disable and enable SIP, but is there an easier way to remove ACLs from a user's library?  I want to move and/or copy some things from my admin account to my regular account and SIP prevents even `sudo` from doing it.

Four shutdown/reboot cycles just for this is a nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

First, of all you do not need 4 cycles. To enable SIP, you can enter the command below, then restart the Mac.

```
csrutil clear
```

You should get the message shown below.

```
Successfully cleared System Integrity Protection. Please restart the machine for the changes to take effect.
```

You can disable SIP on a single restart, if you install rEFInd. If properly installed, you can select rEFInd from the Mac Startup Manager. From the rEFInd menu, you can disable SIP and then boot to macOS.

So to summarize, you can enable or disable SIP though a single restart. So the total number of cycles can be reduced from 4 to a  total of 2.

As for coping files from one users account to another, I do know were SIP is involved. If one of the accounts has administrator privileges, then you can enter the command below to become the root user.

```
sudo bash
```

Once you are the root user, you can enter the necessary commands to copy files between accounts.

Personally, I do not employ the root user. I just use the Finder application. I move (or copy) the files to the Public folder of one account, then switch users and copy the files from the Public folder to the other account.

Comment: You are correct about part; I forgot about csrutil. However, I do not want to install rEFInd.  As for the other, ACLs prevent tampering with a user’s ~/Library, and SIP prevents removing the ACLs.  Neither Finder nor sudo can get around this, so I suspect ‘sudo bash’ will fare no better.

Comment: Can you give an example where a file has an ACL you can not remove? I ask this, because I can modify ACL's without disabling SIP. I assume you are referring to a particular instance. The command `sudo bash` in itself does not modify ACL's. This command just allows you to become the root user. The root user has elevated privileges. I suppose maybe I should have written `sudo chmod`.

Comment: sudo chmod -RN will remove all ACLs from a directory that is not SIP protected.  It will get errors if the directory is SIP protected.

Comment: @WGroeau: I hoping you would post a particular file or folder in the `~\Library` folder where there are ACLs that can not be removed due to SIP. This would give me something to work with.

Comment: There were tons of messages.  Finally gave up and created a fresh account that can copy over what it wants.  Unfortunately, not transferring ~/Library means all the preferences have to be manually set again.